# How to fire anothing action before a each loop (with ajax) complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, foreach, promise

I have try for the following for a long time and i have no more idea now, anyone can help me please.

I just want to reload the current page after add items to the cart, I have try the stupid way by count, promise then and other else, but all fail.

The problem is... the page already reloaded before the item add to the cart...!
The following is my sample:-

```
        $("#Button").click(function () {
                var CurrentURL = window.location.href;                    
                var SelectedProduct = $('.SelectedProduct').length;
                $('.SelectedProduct').each(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/ShoppingCart/AddToCart",
                        data: { id: $(this).attr('id')},
                        datatype: "json"
                    });

                    --SelectedProduct
                    if (SelectedProduct === 0) {
                        window.location.href = CurrentURL;
                        $('#CartListContent').slideDown()
                    }
                });
        });

        $("#Button").click(function () {
                var CurrentURL = window.location.href;

                var promise = $('.SelectedProduct').each(function () {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/ShoppingCart/AddToCart",
                            data: { id: $(this).attr('id')},
                            datatype: "json"
                        });
                    promise.done(function () {
                        window.location.href = CurrentURL;
                        $('#CartListContent').slideDown()
                    });
                });
                });

            }
        });
```

Comment: why dont you use the success callback?

Comment: because i have a each{} before the ajax...!
if i use success callback, only the first one item can be add to cart...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how much control you have over the server side code, but you should let the API handle adding an array of products to cart, that would make it so much faster and simpler. http://jsfiddle.net/hqn3eufa/

```
$("#Button").on('click', function () {

    var selected_products_ids = [];

    $('.SelectedProduct').each(function () {

        selected_products_ids.push(this.id);

    });


    $.ajax({
        url: "/ShoppingCart/AddToCart",
        data: { ids: selected_products_ids },
        datatype: "json",
        success: function() {
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: thats what I was thinking. The Ids need to go as an array to the server and handled in one call

Comment: it is so great and what i want to know(the push concept.)...
i will try it later and i think i should bee work for me...
thank so much...!

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the success callback of ajax and the reload function:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/ShoppingCart/AddToCart",
  data: { id: $(this).attr('id')},
  datatype: "json",
  success:function(data){
     window.location.reload();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion...! x10000
I had try this before, but the problem is i have a each{} before ajax,
if i use reload in here(ajax success),  only the first item add to the cart and the rest cant!
Or can anyone else let me know how to pass a list to integer in 'data' to the controller??? Thanks a lot...!

Comment: Is the server written by you only? or is it a third party api?

Answer (score 0):

your page reload before the add to cart completes. 
use a callback to find out when the add to cart is completed:

```
   $("#Button").click(function () {
            var CurrentURL = window.location.href;

            var promise = $('.SelectedProduct').each(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/ShoppingCart/AddToCart",
                        data: { id: $(this).attr('id')},
                        datatype: "json"
                    }).success(function () {
                    window.location.href = CurrentURL;
                    $('#CartListContent').slideDown()
                });
            });
            });

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggest..! x100000000000
But it still not work for me!
Still only the first item is added to the cart then stop.(Reset item cannot add to cart)

and the promise still not fire....
i really want to know why the promise cant fire in this case ....
please.... any expert can give me a help...! Thanks.!

Comment: Hi, your right, i had to edit my answer, the success should be on the ajax call and not on the promise object.

Answer (score 0):

Now i use the following way, it is stupid but work:-
Anyother suggestion..!?

```
                var SelectedProduct = $('.SelectedProduct').length;
                $('.SelectedProduct').each(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/ShoppingCart/AddToCart",
                        data: { id: $(this).attr('id')},
                        datatype: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            --SelectedProduct
                            if (SelectedProduct == 0) {
                                window.location.reload()
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
```